# Get resultset from a declare block

Tags: oracle, plsql, datagrip

I've managed to incorporate variables into my pl/sql script and I get the correct result but I cannot figure out how to get it back in the same format as if I executed a plain `select`. I only see examples that use `dbms_output.put_line` which outputs text. How do I get an ordinary *table* out of this:

```sql
declare
    monday date;
    sunday date;
    c sys_refcursor;
    type t is table of MY_TABLE%rowtype;
    r t;
begin

    monday := (sysdate - 7 - to_char(sysdate, 'd') + 2);
    sunday := (sysdate - 7 + to_char(sysdate, 'd'));

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(monday);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sunday);

    select
        *
    bulk collect into
        r
    from
        MY_TABLE
    where
        "Created On" >= monday and
        "Created On" <= sunday
    fetch next 10 rows only;
    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r.COUNT); -- <-- = 10

    -- this might work but doesn't yet...
    open c for select * from r;
    DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(c);
    close c;
end;
```

I found a way that it might be possible to use a cursor with `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT` but I still have issues with the `r`, it says `ORA-00942` that the table name is invalid.

Comment: @Abra I was pretty sure I did this with `type t is table of MY_TABLE%rowtype;`... not?

Comment: @Abra I probably mean a _recordset_ but I'm not sure about the correct term. Virtually the same type as if I just called `select * from table`. This means something that I can easily use on the client side like .net etc.

Comment: you need `open c for select from my_table ...` you can't "select" from a PL/SQL table variable

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm perfectly fine with that. I just want to return the `r`, it doesn't have to be a cursor. I thought it might work but any alternative is welcomed.

Comment: you can do it using a ref cursor, check this example it will help you.https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1401210350504

Comment: What's with " monday := (sysdate - 7 - to_char(sysdate, 'd') + 2);"?  You are subtracting 7 (days) from sysdate, then trying to subract a character string (to_char) from that???  If it works at all it is simply because of a successful _implied_ to_number being applied to your to_char.  Specify correct data types and do not rely on implied conversions.

Comment: @EdStevens magic? ;-) I'll take it into account once I figured out the more pressing issue which is no results at all.

Comment: `select * from r` needs to refer to a table or view named `R`, not a PL/SQL collection variable. If you want to return a cursor, you don't need to populate the collection - just return a cursor querying `MY_TABLE`.

Comment: Also, this construction is called an anonymous block, not a "declare block", and how any returned cursor is handled will depend on the client that calls it.